# Can't cast from RLMObject to a subclass of Object?

Tags: swift, realm

`Song` is a subclass of `RLMObject` (`typealias Object`) and is used throughout my app, including in `searchViewController(_:cellForObject:atIndexPath:)`

```
let song = object as! Song
```

But in my `prepare(for segue:)` method (below), when I try to perform the same downcast, the compiler says "Cast from 'RLMObject' to unrelated type 'Song' always fails."

```
if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
    YpbApp.currentRequest?.songObject = results!.object(at: UInt(row)) as? Song
}
```

This doesn't makes sense, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RLMObject` is not a typealias for `Object`; they are different classes entirely that have different interfaces. It sounds like you are trying to mix the Swift and Objective-C APIs, which is not supported.

Comment: I see. I've been able to accomplish what I want using `RealmSearchViewController`'s `didSelect(object: atIndexPath:)` method. Looking at `RealmSearchViewController`s `cell(for row: at indexPath:)` implementation, it looks like if I did want to cast `RLMObject` to a subclass of `Object` I'd need to first cast the `RLMObject` to `RLMObjectBase` and then cast that to `Object` and then cast that to my subclass. However `RLMObjectBase` is not accessible in my subclass. Is there a framework to import to do this multi-part casting myself, or is `RLMObjectBase` inaccessible?